# VS2015 no longer tracks remote Git branch after using Atlasian SourceTree

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, atlassian-sourcetree

I get rather frustrated at the Visual Studio 2015 Git integration, so also use Atlasian SourceTree in parallel.

I have got myself into the position where the local repo is synced with the git repository according to SourceTree. In Visual Studio it says :

"The current branch does not track the remote branch. Publish the branch to push the changes to the origin remote and set the upstream branch".

Sourcetree works fine however.

I've pushed Publish and the project is now tracking the remote branch again. But it's not clear what a publish does? No commits or pushes seem to have happened? Is it just amending something in a VS file to say its connected with the remote repo ? Also, why do they disconnect sometimes and I have to republish?

[MSDN link with out the detail of what Publish does...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Code/git/pull-requests#Publishthebranch)